# Changing width of just one column in geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with most values very close to 0, and one value closer to 6. I am asked for a bar plot of each value. I have roughly 4000 observations. With so many observations, geom_col can't seem to fit them all in the plot:

```
test <- data.frame(obs = 1:5000, value = abs(rnorm(5000, 0, .001)))
test[2500, 'value'] <- test[2500, 'value'] + 6
ggplot(test, aes(obs, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw()
ggplot(test[2400:2600,], aes(obs, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If I narrow the number of observations graphed, my single large value is plotted:

[image]

Is it possible to change the thickness of just the single large observation so I can still display the full range of data?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on `geom_col` or trying some hacks via `geom_rect` to change the width of the plot you can simply use `geom_line` and optionally add a `geom_point` to make a dot or lollipop plot which is basically the same as a barplot. Try this

BTW: Maybe using a log-scale is also a good option.

```r
set.seed(42)

library(ggplot2)

test <- data.frame(obs = 1:5000, value = abs(rnorm(5000, 0, .001)))
test[2500, 'value'] <- test[2500, 'value'] + 6

ggplot(test, aes(obs, value, color = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>